# Lost form model binding after ajax call

Tags: jquery

I get `$('#form').serialize() = ""` after my ajax call:

```
$('#continueBtn').bind('click', function () {
    var url = $('#form').attr('action') + setFlowEvent('continue');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        cache:false,
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success : function(response) {
            var newContent = $($.parseHTML(response)).find("#ajax-content");
            $('#ajax-content').html(newContent);
            bindAjaxSubmit();
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error!");
        }
    });
});
```

And I have next jsp code:

```
<div id="ajax-content">  
    <form:form id="form" modelAttribute="model" action="${actionURL}" method="post">
        <input id="field1" type="text" value="1" name="field1"></input>
        <input id="field2" type="text" value="2" name="field2"></input>
        <button id="continueBtn">continue</button>  
    </form:form> 
</div>
```

Comment: You need to ask a question. I have no idea what you need help wiht.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't see how the value of a serialised form after an AJAX request is relevant? Does the request work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you're going to want to play around with this some - but I think what is happening is that you are nesting the response #ajax-content within the existing #ajax-content.

So here's a suggestion...

```
<div id="target-area">
  <div id="ajax-content">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

then for your ajax try doing the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#target-area").on("click", "#continueButton", function() {
        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : url,
                cache:false,
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                dataType: "html",
                success : function(response) {
                    var newContent = $($.parseHTML(response)).find("#ajax-content");
                    $('#target-area').html(newContent);
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

By doing the above, you'll have automatic capture of the button event provided that the ajax response provides the same or similar body content.